# Navbar fixed at the top of div

Tags: html, css

I've tried many technics and I can't seem to fix this issue.
I would like my menu to always stay at the top of it's parent div. I've made a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/acanana/pen/MwYZPq) of my layout.

Here's the html of my menu and it's parents:

```
<div id="main-wrapper" class="background-yellow">
    <!-- center column -->
    <div id="center-wrapper">
        <nav id="navbar">
            <div id="navbar-wrapper">
                <ul id="main-nav">
                    <li>&Eacute;dito</li>
                    <li>Programme</li>
                    <li>Participants</li>
                    <li>Situation</li>
                    <li>&Agrave; propos</li>
                    <li>Infos</li>
                    <li>Newsletter</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's their css:

```
#main-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#center-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}

#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

#navbar-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 666;
}

#main-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

--EDIT--
Managed to fix the problem, thanks to Zac.Ledyard, now I need `#navbar` to be 100% of it's parent div, that is `#center-wrapper`.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: It appears to be staying at the top of the div. Do you mean you want it to stay at the top of the viewport?

Comment: Exactly, sorry for the confusion :-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your CSS id selectors is named wrong. Change #navbar-container to #navbar-wrapper

```
#navbar-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 666;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel stupid now... anyways now when setting `#navbar-wrapper` width to 100%, it takes 100% of the full screen. How to make it as wide as it's container div `#center-wrapper`? I updated the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/acanana/pen/MwYZPq) .

Comment: Set `width: inherit;` for both #navbar and #navbar wrapper

Answer (score 0):

The method is simple.

Position:relative for a parent element
Position:absolute for a child element

That way the child element always binds to the top of it's parent element.

Any absolute positioned element has a position in the coordinates of the nearest relative positioned parent ( if none are present - the document itself )

It's really unclear from your page code what's going on there , and what you're trying to achieve.

To bind an element to the top of the -page- ( not to scroll with it ) you need to use position:fixed

Comment: Hello, I want `#navbar` to always stay on top of the viewport and to have the width of it's parent div, that is `#center-wrapper`.